# Can I use Perl script in PhoneGap for native Android and iOS apps?

Tags: android, ios, perl, html, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap. I'm building a native app for Android and iOS. And would like to know, whether I can use Perl script in Perl? If yes, how can I add them in the PhoneGap (Android) Eclipse? If not is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can add a Perl script straight into PhoneGap. It definitely wouldn't be cross-platform compatible, even if you find some way to do it, which is one of the main reasons to use PhoneGap.

Your solutions are to either write your code in JavaScript or to use an Ajax request to contact your Perl script running over the web. In the latter case that part of your application won't work if the user is using the app in airplane mode or where she has no network signal.